# Center the content of my dynamic table css php

Tags: php, css, styles, echo, center

I am trying to center the content of my dynamic table. I am using the chosen element from jquery library. I want all the text from my table to be in the center. I have tried all the usual ways but i cannot have the text in the center.
My code is :

```
<tbody id="tbody_chosen">
<?php foreach($table as $row){
$num = $row->total_quantity - $row->available_quantity;
echo "<tr>
        <td>{$row->id}</td>
        <td>{$row->name}</td>
        <td>{$row->total_quantity}</td>
        <td>{$num}</td>
        <td>{$row->available_quantity}</td>
        <td>{$row->inOrder}</td>";
if(have_access("manager"))
    //TODO here we have to use the product's supplier ID
    echo "<td>
            <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selector[]\" value=\"{$row->id}\" id=\"selector-{$row->id}\"/>
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"selector_id[]\" id=\"selector_id-{$row->id}\" value=\"{$row->supplied_by}\" />
        </td>";
echo "</tr>";
} ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: In your css file : `tr{text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 1):

Give this in your tr

```
<tr style='text-align:center;'>
```

Comment: Not working i have tried it and i want the <td> elements to be centered.

Comment: Then give <td style="text-align:center;">

Comment: The same not working.And it has to be <td style='text-align:center'> not with double "

Comment: may be ya you change it to single qoute because you are printing it using php.

Answer (score 0):

td,th {align: center; } in your CSS